# Intent of Data Annotations Model Binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, data-annotations

The article [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs) mentions the use of Data Annotations Model Binder that is available [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471).

Does anyone know what it's intent is? To do DA validation, I don't need a special Model binder in MVC 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first release of ASP.Net MVC didn't support validation via Data Annotations as part of the framework.   The intent of the linked codeplex code was to specifically allow usage of attribute oriented validation (which was in high demand) as a stopgap to the solution that was implemented in the second release.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataType

Specify the datatype of a property
DisplayName

specify the display name for a property.
DisplayFormat

specify the display format for a property like different format for Date proerty.
Required

Specify a property as required.
ReqularExpression

validate the value of a property by specified regular expression pattern.
Range

validate the value of a property with in a specified range of values.
StringLength

specify min and max length for a string property.
MaxLength

specify max length for a string property.
Bind

specify fields to include or exclude when adding parameter or form values to model properties.
ScaffoldColumn
```

### specify fields for hiding from editor forms.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Employee.Models
{
[Bind(Exclude = "EmpId")]
public class Employee
{
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int EmpId { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Employee Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Name is required")]
[StringLength(100,MinimumLength=3)]
public String EmpName { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Address is required")]
[StringLength(300)]
public string Address { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Salary is required")]
[Range(3000, 10000000,ErrorMessage = "Salary must be between 3000 and 10000000")]
public int Salary{ get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
[MaxLength(50)]
[RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
}
}
```